# Every natural number $n$ can be written as $n=s-t$ with $\omega(s)=\omega(t)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Can we prove the following statement ?

> Let $\omega(m)$ denote the number of all distinct prime factors of a positive integer $m$.
>
> Prove that every  natural  number $n$ can  be  written  as $n=s-t$, where $s$ and $t$ are positive integers with $\omega(s)=\omega(t)$, in other words, as the difference of two positive integers with the same number of distinct prime factors.

- If $n=1$ , we can choose $\ s=3\ $ and $\ t=2$.
- If $n$ is even , we can choose $\ s=2n\ $ and $\ t=n$.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $2n$ and $n$ have the same number of prime factors, so $n = 2n-n$ is a solution

Comment: Also, if $n$ is coprime to $6$, $2n$ and $3n$ have the same number of prime factors, so $$n=3n-2n$$ does the job.

Comment: And if $n$ is an odd multiple of $3$, take a Fermat prime $p$ that is not a factor of $n$. Then $p-1$ is a power of $2$ so $pn$ and $(p-1)n$ have the same number of prime factors.

Comment: We can also use a Mersenne-prime $M$ that does not divide the odd number $n$. Then, $M+1$ is a power of two and $$n=(M+1)n-Mn$$ does the job. Hence, if infinite many Mersenne primes exist, we are done.

Comment: @CharlesMadeline No, because there could be finite many. But there are almost surely other approaches leading to a solution.

Comment: @CharlesMadeline At least we can be sure that a counterexample , if there is actually one, must be huge.

Comment: I'm not sure really. What if you are left with the case "all Mersenne and Fermat prime numbers divide $n$" ? Since they are all odd, you can not use only them to find a solution (which would have the same number of factors as $n$). So, again, you must find other prime numbers, but which ones ?

Comment: We have other possibilities. If we find a number $m$, such that $m$ and $m+1$ are both coprime to $n$ and have the same number of prime factors, we have found a solution as well.

Comment: Indeed. Because of the Catalan conjecture, this number of prime factor cannot be $1$ (otherwise the only solution is $2^3+1=3^2$). I think it should be doable to find solutions to $p^aq^b = p'^{a'}q'^{b'}+1$

Comment: @CharlesMadeline Moreover, we only concentrated on solutions of the form $(k+1)n-kn$. This is not required in the question. But I agree that the proof is not yet finished.

Comment: @rafa Please verify that my edit did not change the intent of your question !

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to prove this directly though, and it is pretty simple:

**Case 1: Both 2 and 3 divide $n$, or neither 2 nor 3 divide $n$:** Then let $s=3n$ and $t=2n$.

**Case 2: 3 does not divide $n$ but $2$ does:** Then let $s=2n$ and $t=n$.

**Case 3: 3 divides $n$ but 2 does not:** Then let $p$ be the smallest odd prime that does not divide $n$. Then let $s=pn$ and let $t=(p-1)n$. [Note that $p-1$ is the product of smaller odd primes, all of which divide $n$ [by def'n of $p$], and 2, which does not. So $\omega(pn) = \omega(n) +1$ [because $p$ doesn't divide $n$], while $\omega((p-1)n) = \omega(n) +1$ as well, because the one prime factor of $p-1$ that does not divide $n$ is 2.]

Comment: Case 2 works for all even $n$ and Case 3 works for all odd $n$, so Case 1 is not needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is even then $n$ and $2n$ have the same number of prime factors, and so
$$n=2n−n,$$
shows that $n$ is the difference of two natural numbers having the same number of prime factors.

If $n$ is odd then let $q$ be the smallest odd prime number not dividing $n$. Then $q+1$ is even, and its odd factors all divide $n$. It follows that $qn$ and $(q+1)n$ have the same number of prime factors, and so
$$n=(q+1)n−qn,$$
shows that $n$ is the difference of two natural numbers having the same number of prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

The (generalized) Bunyakovsky conjecture implies that we always find a solution.

To show this, assume that there are infinite many positive integers $p$, such that $$2p+1$$ $$2p+3$$ $$2p^2+4p+1$$ are simultaneously prime. Then, we can choose $p>n$ satisfying this property. Then, $$(2p+1)(2p+3)n-2(2p^2+4p+1)n=n$$ is a solution, whenever $n$ is odd (the even case has already been solved).

There are plenty of other possibilities to choose the expressions, so the given statement is in fact much weaker than Bunyakovsky's conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

- If $\ n\ $ is even, see [user3733558](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/329252/user3733558)'s comments or [Servaes's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074280/expressing-every-natural-number-as-a-difference-of-two-numbers/4074583#4074583) for a much simply argument than the one I originally gave.
- If $\ n\ $ is odd, let $  q\ $ be the smallest odd prime not dividing $\ n\ $.  Then all the odd prime factors of $\ q-1\ $ must be factors of $\ n\ $, and both $\ qn\ $ and $\ (q-1)n\ $ must therefore have exactly one more prime factor than $\ n\ $.

Comment: If $n$ is even, there's no need for case work, $2n$ and $n$ have the same number of prime factors.

Comment: How silly of me not to notice that.

Comment: oh, I've been looking for my glasses while they were sitting on my nose enough times to know best how silly one can be, trust me ;)

Answer (score -1):

If $d$ is any even number, Schinzel's hypothesis implies the existence of a prime $p$, such that $p+d$ is prime as well. In this case , the pair $(p,p+d)$ does the job.

Let $d$ be an odd positive integer.

$$[dx(x+y),2d\frac{x^2+xy+1}{2}]$$ is a suitable pair with difference $d$ , if all the numbers $$x,x+y,\frac{x^2+xy+1}{2}$$ are odd distinct prime numbers , all larger than the largest prime factor of $d$.

With $$p=x,q=\frac{x^2+1}{2},y=2k$$ where $p$ is an odd prime , we get the numbers $$p,p+2k,q+pk$$ Note that $q$ is an integer, if $p$ is an odd prime. Schinzel's hypothesis predicts infinite many $k$ such that all the $3$ numbers are prime because $p$ and $q$ must be coprime. Since $p$ is arbitary , we can establish large enough primes and hence get the desired solution.

So, if Schinzel's hypothesis holds, we can find a pair with every given difference.

Comment: if $d$ is even, then $d = 2d - d$, and the OP's requirement is fulfilled, is it not?

Comment: @user3733558 In fact, that makes it easier.