# Expressing every natural number as a difference of two numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that each natural number can be written as the difference of two natural numbers
> having the same number of prime factors.

**What I Tried**: Upon some inspection, I can see that all odd numbers, and all numbers of the form $4k$ can be written as a difference of two squares, because :-
$$\rightarrow n= p^2 - q^2 = (p+q)(p-q)$$
Works for all odd $n$ if you take $(p + q) = n$ , $(p - q) = 1$ and similarly works for all $n$ of the form $4k$ if you take both $p,q$ to be even, directly factoring out a $4$.

The problem with this, however, is that both the squares $p^2$ and $q^2$ aren't necessarily going to have the same prime factors as I expected, (like $6^2 - 5^2$) but I couldn't get any more ideas.

Another thing left to solve here is to show that, all numbers of the form $(4k + 2)$ can be represented as a difference of two numbers having same number of prime factors. I noticed by some experiments that all these numbers can be represented as a difference of two primes, like :- 
$1)$ $2 = 5 - 3.$ 
$2)$ $18 = 29 - 11.$ 
$3)$ $42 = 47 - 5.$

And so on. But I was not able to get a proof of it. 
Regarding all my attempts with this problem, can anyone help me with the solution?

Thank You.